# Creating an adjusted boxplot using custom bounds in matplotlib boxplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

As part of my research I'm trying to plot a pandas dataframe using a adjusted boxpolt.

I have calculated medcoule value stored in variable mc.

Also calculated the quartiles using `q1, q3= np.percentile(sorteddf['Depth'],[25,75])`

calulated IQR using the above values iqr = q3-q1

Now, I've calculated the lower and upper bounds using

lb = q1 - (1.5 * exp(-3.5 * mc) * iqr)
ub = q3 + (1.5 * exp(4 * mc) * iqr)

The values I received are (lb,ub) - (0.9547039248665222, 83.89722504971635)

I tried the below code to plot the boxplot

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.boxplot(sorteddf.Depth, whis=range(1,84))

But I don't get the whiskers.

Comment: I believe I figured out the mistake.

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots() ax1.boxplot(sorteddf.Depth, whis=range[1,84])

I guess it should be `[ ]` instead of `( )`